# How to select records with one date at least half an hour longer than the other?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select records with one date at least half an hour longer than the other?

My example:

```
id | book_id | date1               | date2
1. | 1.      | 2020-11-08 10:20:00 | 2020-11-08 10:40:00 (20 minutes diff)
2. | 3.      | 2020-11-08 10:30:00 | 2020-11-08 11:51:00 (1 hour and 21 minutes diff - OK) 
3. | 2.      | 2020-11-08 10:25:00 | 2020-11-08 10:27:00 (2 minutes diff)
4. | 4.      | 2020-11-08 10:21:00 | 2020-11-08 10:51:00 (31 minutes diff - OK)
```

In this example I would like to get the records with ID: 2 and 4.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date2 > date1
```

Comment: You could use `TIMEDIFF` like this : `SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMEDIFF(date2, date1) > '00:30:00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where date2 > date1 + interval 30 minute
```